# Magento - steps checkout and additional module

Tags: magento

Thanks for this forum. I often read it and this is my first question.
The question concerns Magento (1.9.1.0). I wanted to add an additional module that allows customer to write a comment on the order. I've been able to find a module that suits my need on the web. It works perfectly, but there is a big problem: it joins in the final step of the checkout (in particular, after the payment phase). And so, if the customer pays by bank transfer, marking or similar payments, the problem doesn't arise: Magento passes to the next step (order comment) and then order completion. 
The problem arises in case of Paypal payment, as Magento redirects customer to Paypal.com and, after making the payment, returns to the store by the end of the order (without going to the next step of the comment). The comment form consisted of 19 files that, once installed in Magento, don't modify any existing files.
I would like to include this form after shipping_method step (and not after payment step) and, therefore, I think I have to modify the file (of the module) that is called Abstract.php (app/code/community/Brainvire/Ordercomment/Controller/Onepage/Abstract.php). 
I would be very grateful if you could help me edit that file.

```
<?php
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php';
class Brainvire_Ordercomment_Controller_Onepage_Abstract extends 
Mage_Checkout_OnepageController {

/*
* Saving the Payment at Checkout
*/
public function savePaymentAction()
{
    $this->_expireAjax();
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('payment', array());


        try {
            $result = $this->getOnepage()->savePayment($data);
        }
        catch (Mage_Payment_Exception $e) {
            if ($e->getFields()) {
                $result['fields'] = $e->getFields();
            }
            $result['error'] = $e->getMessage();
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $result['error'] = $e->getMessage();
        }
        $redirectUrl = $this->getOnePage()->getQuote()->getPayment()->getCheckoutRedirectUrl();
        if (empty($result['error']) && !$redirectUrl) {
            $this->loadLayout('checkout_onepage_ordercomment');

            $result['goto_section'] = 'ordercomment';
        }

        if ($redirectUrl) {
            $result['redirect'] = $redirectUrl;
        }

        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Zend_Json::encode($result));
    }
}

/*
* Saving the order comment 
*/
public function saveOrdercommentAction()
{
    $this->_expireAjax();
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {


        $_brainvire_Ordercomment = $this->getRequest()->getPost('ordercomment');

        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setBrainvireOrdercomment($_brainvire_Ordercomment);

        $result = array();

        $redirectUrl = $this->getOnePage()->getQuote()->getPayment()->getCheckoutRedirectUrl();
        if (!$redirectUrl) {
            $this->loadLayout('checkout_onepage_review');

            $result['goto_section'] = 'review';
            $result['update_section'] = array(
                'name' => 'review',
                'html' => $this->_getReviewHtml()
            );

        }

        if ($redirectUrl) {
            $result['redirect'] = $redirectUrl;
        }

        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Zend_Json::encode($result));
    }
}    
}
```

How do I edit this php code to insert Ordercomment after shipping_method step and before payment step?
Thanks
GS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to move the order-comment section by editing two files:

First: `Brainvire\Ordercomment\Block\Onepage.php`

```
class Brainvire_Ordercomment_Block_Onepage extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage
{
    /**
     * getting the steps of Checkout page
     */
    public function getSteps()
    {
        ...

        $stepCodes = array('billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'ordercomment', 'payment', 'review'); // moved 'ordercomment' before 'payment'

        ...
    }
}
```

And then the file you mentioned: `Brainvire\Ordercomment\Controller\Onepage\Abstract.php`

Remove the `savePaymentAction()` method and replace with this:

```
class Brainvire_Ordercomment_Controller_Onepage_Abstract extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController {


     /**
     * Shipping method save action
     */
    public function saveShippingMethodAction()
    {
        if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
            return;
        }
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('shipping_method', '');
            $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveShippingMethod($data);
            /*
            $result will have erro data if shipping method is empty
            */
            if(!$result) {
                Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method',
                        array('request'=>$this->getRequest(),
                            'quote'=>$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()));
                $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->collectTotals();
                $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));

                if (empty($result['error']) && !$redirectUrl) {
                    $this->loadLayout('checkout_onepage_ordercomment');
                    $result['goto_section'] = 'ordercomment';
                }
            }
            $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->collectTotals()->save();
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
        }
    }

    /*
    * Saving the order comment 
    */
    public function saveOrdercommentAction()
    {
        $this->_expireAjax();
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $_brainvire_Ordercomment = $this->getRequest()->getPost('ordercomment');

            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setBrainvireOrdercomment($_brainvire_Ordercomment);

            $result = array();
            $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
            $result['update_section'] = array(
                'name' => 'payment-method',
                'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
            );
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Zend_Json::encode($result));
        }
    }
}
```

*Once you get this working, you should move these customizations into an override module, or at least copy the modified files to app/code/local, so the original code stays intact.*

Comment: I regret you a lot for dedicating some of your time to help me.

I think you've identified what the problem is and you has given an absolutely correct answer. However, I think there is a small imperfection.

The comments step appears correctly before the payment step and after shipping_method step, however, after entering a comment, the store redirects the customer to the page store.com/checkout/cart/.

Do you think you can find where error is?

Thank you

Comment: @juanmi22 Good catch! I don't know how that one slipped past me. Anyway, I edited my answer and it should be working now. Basically, it's just the `saveOrdercommentAction()` method that I updated.

Comment: I'm sorry if I reopen this discussion after so many weeks. The code you passed me works very well. However, in magento backend, in orders list, in column "order comment", when payment method chosen is Paypal, the following text appears: "Prendi importo di 18,12 € online. ID transazione: "35H221....". What may be due? Can an interference with Paypal? Can you suggest me how to solve?
Thanks always

Comment: Usually order comments are added automatically whenever a transaction takes place, with the payment gateway and transaction ID. That appears to be a note that Paypal processed the amount. I'm guessing that the comment is added before the checkout is completed, so it gets added first that that's the only comment you see, since Brainvire seems to only show the first comment.